# Attaching a file to an email C#

Tags: c#, email, office-interop, email-attachments

I've tried many of the solutions provided on this site to attach a file to an email, but no matter what I try I always get the "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again" message at the line where I try to attach the file to my outlook mailitem.

```
  try
        {
            App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            MailItem mailItem = App.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mailItem.Subject = Subject;
            mailItem.To = To;
            mailItem.CC = CC;
            mailItem.BCC = BCC;
            mailItem.Body = Body;

            // make sure a filename was passed
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileAtachment) == false)
            {
                // need to check to see if file exists before we attach !
                if (!File.Exists(FileAtachment))
                    MessageBox.Show("Attached document " + FileAtachment + " does not exist", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileAtachment);
                    mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                }
            }
            mailItem.Display();     // display the email
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

Can anyone offer any idea how to get this to work ? I can send emails without any problem, but when I try to add an attachment it doesn't work :(

Comment: You're adding a `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` to the Outlook mail item, but it expects an Outlook attachment

Answer (score 6):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachments.Add) method accepts a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment, but not the attachment object:

```
            App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            MailItem mailItem = App.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
             
            mailItem.Subject = Subject;
            mailItem.To = To;
            mailItem.CC = CC;
            mailItem.BCC = BCC;
            mailItem.Body = Body;

            // make sure a filename was passed
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileAtachment) == false)
            {
                // need to check to see if file exists before we attach !
                if (!File.Exists(FileAtachment))
                    MessageBox.Show("Attached document " + FileAtachment + " does not exist", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                {
                    Attachment attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add("D:\\text.txt", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                }
            }
            mailItem.Display();     // display the email
```

And don't mix .Net and OOM objects in the code:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileAtachment);
                    mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` type belongs to BCL and can't be used for Outlook.

Comment: Maybe link to the dotnet API would be more appropriate. [Attachments.Add(Object, Object, Object, Object) Method (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add?view=outlook-pia) --- That having said, maybe you can just omit the argument instead of writing explicitly `Type.Missing`? I haven't tested.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Outlook 2016 and for me, displaying the Mail before adding the Attachment(s) did the trick (as long as the Attachment is a valid file path)

```
    App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

    MailItem mailItem = App.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mailItem.Subject = Subject;
    mailItem.To = To;
    mailItem.CC = CC;
    mailItem.BCC = BCC;
    mailItem.Body = Body;

    // display the item before adding the attachments
    mailItem.Display();     // display the email

    // make sure a filename was passed
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileAtachment) == false)
    {
        // need to check to see if file exists before we attach !
        if (!File.Exists(FileAtachment))
            MessageBox.Show("Attached document " + FileAtachment + " does not exist", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else
        {
            Attachment attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add("D:\\text.txt", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I am using Outlook 2016 and for me, displaying the Mail before adding the Attachment(s) did the trick (as long as the Attachment is a valid file path)

Answer (score 0):

Attachments.Add needs a string as an argument. That string must be a fully qualified name of the  file that you are trying to attach.

Save the stream to a temporary file, pass the file name to Attachments.Add, delete the file.

You can get details  from : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17efe46b-18fe-450f-9f6e-d8bb116161d8/attach-stream-data-with-outlook-mail-client?forum=outlookdev